# Keyboard shortcuts in Tmux deactivated after using xclip

Tags: tmux, xclip

I am using the following configuration in my .tmux.conf to copy text to-and fro from xclip

```
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard"
bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
```

If I run C-prefix C-c for e.g, the text is pasted into another application but after that none of the tmux commands work in the tmux terminal (e.g. C-prefix [ to go into copy-mode etc.)

What is wrong in my config?

Comment: Does it work if you change the second binding to the following? `bind C-v run "</dev/null xclip -o -sel clipboard|tmux load-buffer - \\; paste-buffer"`

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen: It does not work :(

Answer (score 13):

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#X_clipboard_integration:

> It seems xclip does not close STDOUT after it has read from tmux's buffer. As such, tmux doesn't know that the copy task has completed, and continues to /await xclip's termination, thereby rendering the window manager unresponsive. To work around this, you can execute the command via run-shell -b instead of run, you can redirect STDOUT of xclip to /dev/null, or you can use an alternative command like xsel.

Updating the `PREFIX C-c` binding to the following fixed it for me:

```
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard > /dev/null"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, a switch to `xsel` instead of `xclip` did the trick.

Comment: Can you share your usage with it? Might attract more people to use your answer.

Comment: Wish I did that when I still used it. Nowadays I don't use tmux anymore :-(